# How to change move in my TicTacToe game in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a TicTacToe game and faced with a some problem.
After put the "X" I need to change `changeMove` to `true` in `ChangeMove()` function to put next move as "O" in another place.
I need to check `place.sprite == null` too, because I don't want to change put move again.
In the `If` block I'm changing changeMove to apposite value but it isn't changing(I mean when I'm calling OnMouseDown method second time, I can't get into the `else if` block).
Here is my inspector of `MainCamera`:

[image]

I created a script(PutMove.cs) that inherits all the methods and fields from **LogicOfGame.cs** besides `private bool changeMove` only for clickable squares to put move there:
Here is my LogicOfGame.cs, PutMove.cs scripts and inspector of first square:
The square's inspector:

[image]

LogicOfGame.cs:

```
public class LogicOfGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer place;
    private bool changeMove;
    public Image X;
    public Image O;

    public void ChangeMove() 
    {
        if (!changeMove && place.sprite == null)
        {
            place.sprite = X.sprite;
            changeMove = !changeMove;
        }

        else if (changeMove && place.sprite == null)
        {
            place.sprite = O.sprite;
            changeMove = !changeMove;
        }
    }
{
```

PutMove.cs:

```
public class PutMove : LogicOfGame
{
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        ChangeMove();
    }
}
```

I also tried to change `changeMove` value in another method and call it in `OnMouseDown()` method, but isn't helped

```
public bool ChangeMove(bool changeMove) 
{
    return !changeMove;
}

public class PutMove : LogicOfGame
{
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        //renamed the ChangeMove()
        //And left only place.sprite = X.sprite;
        PutMove();     
        changeMove = ChangeMove(changeMove);
    }
}
```

How can I change value of `changeMove` at last?

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint and step through the code. When you get to the `if/else` conditions, is `place.sprite == null` actually `true`? I don't know Unity, but it seems to me this would only be `true` the first time the method is called. After that, it's set to `X.sprite` or `O.sprite`, so subsequent calls would have no affect since the conditions would evaluate to `false`.

If this is the case, then removing the `null` check should resolve the issue:

```
public void ChangeMove() 
{
    if (changeMove) place.sprite = O.sprite;
    else place.sprite = X.sprite;
    changeMove = !changeMove;
}
```

You may even be able to get rid of the `changeMove` variable and just examine the value of `place.sprite`:

```
public void ChangeMove() 
{
    if (place.sprite == O.sprite) place.sprite = X.sprite;
    else place.sprite = O.sprite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ChangeMove()` is only true once, as you set the value of `place.sprite` as its called the first time, and then it can never be changed again.

As Rufus L says, remove the `place.sprite == null` condition and there shouldn't be an issue, as it looks like the function (as is) only handles the very first move only.